# Unable to extract key value from dictionaries present in double list in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Unable to extract key value from dictionaries present in double list in python

I have 2d list

```
print(sent[:2])
```

output is :

```
[[{'label': 'negative', 'score': '0.99'}]
 [{'label': 'positive', 'score': '0.96'}]]
```

**I'm trying to extract label key values i.e. negative and positive**

I tried running the below code, but it's returning an empty list

```
sentiment = [i['label'] for i in sent if 'label' in i]
print(sentiment)
```

output is :

```
[]
```

I'm expecting the output to be:

```
['negative', 'positive']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, each dict being a singleton-list in unnecessary.
But that being a given, the right way to access a dictionary field is by the key. So how about -

```
sentiment = [x[0]['label'] for x in sent]
print(sentiment)
```

If your `if` clause is due to not always having a `label` key, then just add that if in the list comprehension -

```
sentiment = [x[0]['label'] for x in sent if 'label' in x[0].keys()]
```

And if you want a default value for non-existing labels, then using `.get` is very useful -

```
sentiment = [x[0].get('label', 'No label') for x in sent]
```

Comment: just use `.get` instead @ShlomiF

Answer (score 1):

You have a doubly nested list, with each sublist only having one item.  Therefore, you need to access the first element of the sublist from your list comprehension:

```py
sent = [[{'label': 'negative', 'score': '0.99'}], [{'label': 'positive', 'score': '0.96'}]]
sentiment = [i[0]['label'] for i in sent if 'label' in i[0]]
print(sentiment)  # ['negative', 'positive']
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is something you need to do quite often, we can have this as a simple function.

```
sent = [[{'label': 'negative', 'score': '0.99'}],
 [{'label': 'positive', 'score': '0.96'}]]

def doubleListKeyExtractor(inputList:list, labelStr: str):
    cur = 0
    output = []

    while cur < len(t):
        for each in t[cur]:
            output.append(each[labelStr])
        cur += 1
    
    return output

print(doubleListKeyExtractor(sent,'label'))
print(doubleListKeyExtractor(sent,'score'))

//Results
['negative', 'positive']
['0.99', '0.96']
```